# Updating list in nested loop in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop, lm

I am re-writting an earlier question I had which was deleted for lack of details.

I would like to extract the p-value of a number of regression that I am running with a loop and have the p-values stored for each of the independant variable as a list. My issue is with storing the new lists correctly. You will find below the code, the sample data and the expected results.

Many thanks!

```
ind_var <- list(c("Man","Below_Master","Worker","Rural", "Less_than_26"))
depending_var <- list(c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4", "Q5", "Q6"))


x <- list()

for (var_p in depending_var) {
 { for (var in ind_var)  
    
x1 <- lm(paste(var, "~", var_p), data = Ech_final_nom_SD, weights = pond)
 
x[[var_p]] <- summary(x1)$coefficients[,4]    #Where shit hits the fan

  }
}
```

Here is the sample data:

| ID | Man | Below_Master | Worker | Rural | Less than 26 | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | Q4 | Q5 | Q6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 4 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 4 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 5 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 6 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 7 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 8 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 3 |
| 9 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 10 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |

Expected results (with different p-values for all) :

```
x_Man <- list(c("0.0234","0.9894", "0.0045", "0.9892", "0.0229", "0.0254","0.0894", "0.0047", "0.2392", "0.0029"))

x_Below_Master <- list(c("0.0434","0.9854", "0.0545", "0.0092", "0.0729", "0.0254","0.0894", "0.0047", "0.2392", "0.0029"))

x_Worker <- list(c("0.0234","0.9894", "0.0045", "0.9892", "0.0229", "0.0254","0.0894", "0.0047", "0.2392", "0.0029"))

x_Rural <- list(c("0.0234","0.9894", "0.0045", "0.9892", "0.0229", "0.0254","0.0894", "0.0047", "0.2392", "0.0029"))

x_Less_than_26 <- list(c("0.0234","0.9894", "0.0045", "0.9892", "0.0229", "0.0254","0.0894", "0.0047", "0.2392", "0.0029"))
```

Comment: Do you want to do one model per dependant variable as well? so 6*5 models? or just one model per independent variable?

Comment: You are using the dependent variables as independent and vice-versa.

Comment: @Maël for the output I would need the answer per each independent variable as you suggested in your answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way with the nested `for` loop in the question. The results object is of a different shape, it's a data.frame.

```r
ind_var <- c("Man","Below_Master","Worker","Rural", "Less_than_26")
depending_var <- c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4", "Q5", "Q6")

n_rows <- length(depending_var) * length(ind_var)
x <- data.frame(
  dependent = character(n_rows),
  independent = character(n_rows),
  pval_intercept = numeric(n_rows),
  pval_indep = numeric(n_rows)
)

i <- 0L
for (var_p in depending_var) {
  for (var in ind_var) {
    i <- i + 1L
    fmla <- reformulate(var, response = var_p)
    x1 <- lm(fmla, data = Ech_final_nom_SD, weights = pond)
    x[i, "dependent"] <- var_p
    x[i, "independent"] <- var
    x[i, "pval_intercept"] <- summary(x1)$coefficients[1, 4]
    x[i, "pval_indep"] <- summary(x1)$coefficients[2, 4]
  }
}
x
#>    dependent  independent pval_intercept pval_indep
#> 1         Q1          Man   9.160936e-04 0.80277173
#> 2         Q1 Below_Master   2.026789e-03 0.18690481
#> 3         Q1       Worker   2.231686e-04 0.34553732
#> 4         Q1        Rural   2.331972e-04 0.54473730
#> 5         Q1 Less_than_26   1.768920e-02 0.05845715
#> 6         Q2          Man   3.287724e-05 0.27313922
#> 7         Q2 Below_Master   8.982180e-05 0.72446583
#> 8         Q2       Worker   3.896158e-05 0.56210550
#> 9         Q2        Rural   1.712317e-05 0.38768132
#> 10        Q2 Less_than_26   7.359017e-04 0.93892908
#> 11        Q3          Man   6.976609e-04 0.07359019
#> 12        Q3 Below_Master   3.373039e-02 0.26225475
#> 13        Q3       Worker   1.177118e-02 0.74104616
#> 14        Q3        Rural   3.748440e-03 0.63631632
#> 15        Q3 Less_than_26   3.502726e-02 0.90655491
#> 16        Q4          Man   1.337132e-03 0.47136168
#> 17        Q4 Below_Master   8.923744e-05 0.12647490
#> 18        Q4       Worker   2.199469e-04 0.46193445
#> 19        Q4        Rural   2.862687e-04 1.00000000
#> 20        Q4 Less_than_26   8.392753e-03 0.43036607
#> 21        Q5          Man   3.584230e-05 0.11143429
#> 22        Q5 Below_Master   3.701074e-04 1.00000000
#> 23        Q5       Worker   2.603420e-04 0.35588376
#> 24        Q5        Rural   1.346479e-04 0.74828807
#> 25        Q5 Less_than_26   2.975062e-03 0.62876991
#> 26        Q6          Man   2.911220e-03 0.06558768
#> 27        Q6 Below_Master   1.270703e-03 0.74043945
#> 28        Q6       Worker   1.257419e-03 0.78704595
#> 29        Q6        Rural   7.220649e-04 0.82866767
#> 30        Q6 Less_than_26   5.691830e-03 0.82866767
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

And a solution with a double `lapply` loop.

```r
res <- lapply(depending_var, \(y) {
  lapply(ind_var, \(x) {
    fit <- lm(reformulate(x, y), data = Ech_final_nom_SD, weights = pond)
    data.frame(
      dependent = y,
      independent = x,
      pval_intercept = summary(fit)$coefficients[1, 4],
      pval_indep = summary(fit)$coefficients[2, 4]
    )
  })
})
res <- do.call(rbind, unlist(res, recursive = FALSE))
res
#>    dependent  independent pval_intercept pval_indep
#> 1         Q1          Man   9.160936e-04 0.80277173
#> 2         Q1 Below_Master   2.026789e-03 0.18690481
#> 3         Q1       Worker   2.231686e-04 0.34553732
#> 4         Q1        Rural   2.331972e-04 0.54473730
#> 5         Q1 Less_than_26   1.768920e-02 0.05845715
#> 6         Q2          Man   3.287724e-05 0.27313922
#> 7         Q2 Below_Master   8.982180e-05 0.72446583
#> 8         Q2       Worker   3.896158e-05 0.56210550
#> 9         Q2        Rural   1.712317e-05 0.38768132
#> 10        Q2 Less_than_26   7.359017e-04 0.93892908
#> 11        Q3          Man   6.976609e-04 0.07359019
#> 12        Q3 Below_Master   3.373039e-02 0.26225475
#> 13        Q3       Worker   1.177118e-02 0.74104616
#> 14        Q3        Rural   3.748440e-03 0.63631632
#> 15        Q3 Less_than_26   3.502726e-02 0.90655491
#> 16        Q4          Man   1.337132e-03 0.47136168
#> 17        Q4 Below_Master   8.923744e-05 0.12647490
#> 18        Q4       Worker   2.199469e-04 0.46193445
#> 19        Q4        Rural   2.862687e-04 1.00000000
#> 20        Q4 Less_than_26   8.392753e-03 0.43036607
#> 21        Q5          Man   3.584230e-05 0.11143429
#> 22        Q5 Below_Master   3.701074e-04 1.00000000
#> 23        Q5       Worker   2.603420e-04 0.35588376
#> 24        Q5        Rural   1.346479e-04 0.74828807
#> 25        Q5 Less_than_26   2.975062e-03 0.62876991
#> 26        Q6          Man   2.911220e-03 0.06558768
#> 27        Q6 Below_Master   1.270703e-03 0.74043945
#> 28        Q6       Worker   1.257419e-03 0.78704595
#> 29        Q6        Rural   7.220649e-04 0.82866767
#> 30        Q6 Less_than_26   5.691830e-03 0.82866767
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

But the simplest solution is to remember that `lm` can fit multiple regression models and fit all responses at once.

```r
  resp <- as.matrix(Ech_final_nom_SD[depending_var])
  out <- lapply(ind_var, \(x) {
    fit <- lm(resp ~ get(x), data = Ech_final_nom_SD)
    cfs <- sapply(summary(fit), \(s) s$coefficients[, 4])  
    rownames(cfs)[2] <- x
    cfs
  })
  do.call(rbind.data.frame, out)
#>               Response Q1  Response Q2  Response Q3  Response Q4  Response Q5  Response Q6
#> (Intercept)  0.0009160936 3.287724e-05 0.0006976609 1.337132e-03 0.0000358423 0.0029112201
#> Man          0.8027717312 2.731392e-01 0.0735901860 4.713617e-01 0.1114342894 0.0655876769
#> (Intercept)1 0.0020267889 8.982180e-05 0.0337303906 8.923744e-05 0.0003701074 0.0012707033
#> Below_Master 0.1869048103 7.244658e-01 0.2622547504 1.264749e-01 1.0000000000 0.7404394537
#> (Intercept)2 0.0002231686 3.896158e-05 0.0117711783 2.199469e-04 0.0002603420 0.0012574186
#> Worker       0.3455373232 5.621055e-01 0.7410461602 4.619345e-01 0.3558837647 0.7870459482
#> (Intercept)3 0.0002331972 1.712317e-05 0.0037484405 2.862687e-04 0.0001346479 0.0007220649
#> Rural        0.5447373008 3.876813e-01 0.6363163232 1.000000e+00 0.7482880706 0.8286676662
#> (Intercept)4 0.0176892034 7.359017e-04 0.0350272586 8.392753e-03 0.0029750616 0.0056918299
#> Less_than_26 0.0584571528 9.389291e-01 0.9065549125 4.303661e-01 0.6287699080 0.8286676662
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

## Data

```r
x<-'ID  Man     Below_Master    Worker  Rural   Less_than_26    Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4  Q5  Q6
1   1   1   0   0   1   4   3   1   2   2   1
2   0   0   0   1   1   2   2   2   2   3   1
3   0   1   0   0   1   4   3   1   1   3   1
4   0   0   1   0   0   1   4   1   2   3   1
5   0   1   1   0   1   4   3   4   2   3   2
6   1   0   1   1   1   3   2   1   2   2   2
7   0   1   0   0   0   3   3   3   2   1   2
8   1   0   0   0   1   3   3   1   4   1   3
9   1   0   0   1   1   2   3   1   2   2   3
10  1   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   2   3'
Ech_final_nom_SD <- read.table(textConnection(x), header = TRUE)
pond <- rep(1, nrow(Ech_final_nom_SD))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Rui! I tried using your first option because I like the idea of the data frame output and I understand the logic but I however get the following error message : " Error in doWithOneRestart(return(expr), restart)" and have no output.
Would you know why?

Comment: @DavidPotrel I ran the code in a clean R session and cannot reproduce the error. Does your data match the posted example?

Comment: I will restart the session tonight because from what I read online it might be a R issue. My data does not exactly match the example (it is way bigger), but the structure is similar.

Other question out of curiosity, what does "\" mean in the other two codes? It appears as an error on my version of R.

Comment: @DavidPotrel OK, so that might be the reason for you errors. `\(x)` are the new lambda functions introduced in R 4.2.0. If you are running an older version, use `function(x)`. Or maybe it's time to update R?

Comment: I get the following error now  for the first solution you provided: "error in terms.formula(formula data = data) invalid term in model formula"

Comment: @DavidPotrel In the question you use both `ind_var` and `independent_var`, I have changed all to one, `ind_var`. Are you doing the same in your code? And in the error message there's a comma missing after `formula`.

Comment: Yes I have also changed all to ind_var and you're indeed right there is a missing comma. I wonder if it could be because I have some missing data ? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @DavidPotrel If you have missing data, use `na.action=na.omit` in the `lm` call. Or `na.action=na.exclude`.

Comment: Thank you Rui. Sorry to be bothersome some more. I still get this error message when trying your first option : "Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, "dependent", value = c("Q1", "Q2",  : 
  replacement has 6 rows, data has 1" 
Keep in mind I had to reglect reformulate as it created an error.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```r
l <- lapply(independent_var, function(x) summary(lm(reformulate(depending_var, x), data = Ech_final_nom_SD))$coefficients[, 4])
names(l) <- independent_var
```

output

```r
$Man
(Intercept)          Q1          Q2          Q3          Q4          Q5          Q6 
  0.7006954   0.4183649   0.4814779   0.1129608   0.7429505   0.8469599   0.3121451 

$Below_Master
(Intercept)          Q1          Q2          Q3          Q4          Q5          Q6 
  0.4269917   0.3294021   0.8975661   0.4513400   0.1453265   0.4121115   0.9905834 

$Worker
(Intercept)          Q1          Q2          Q3          Q4          Q5          Q6 
  0.9251373   0.6595554   0.9057457   0.7430144   0.9231273   0.5541379   0.6826245 

$Rural
(Intercept)          Q1          Q2          Q3          Q4          Q5          Q6 
  0.9051546   0.8906284   0.5703472   0.8245217   0.6760297   0.6800893   0.9835419 

$Less_than_26
(Intercept)          Q1          Q2          Q3          Q4          Q5          Q6 
 0.23702999  0.05804822  0.37926448  0.26210405  0.16896185  0.12015247  0.47013899
```

If you want the output to be a dataframe, I'd suggest to apply the same function with `map_dfr` from `purrr`:

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map_dfr(independent_var, 
        function(x) summary(lm(reformulate(depending_var, x), data = Ech_final_nom_SD))$coefficients[, 4]) %>% 
  mutate(ind_var = independent_var, .before = 1)
```

Which gives:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 8
  ind_var      `(Intercept)`     Q1    Q2    Q3    Q4    Q5    Q6
  <chr>                <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Man                  0.701 0.418  0.481 0.113 0.743 0.847 0.312
2 Below_Master         0.427 0.329  0.898 0.451 0.145 0.412 0.991
3 Worker               0.925 0.660  0.906 0.743 0.923 0.554 0.683
4 Rural                0.905 0.891  0.570 0.825 0.676 0.680 0.984
5 Less_than_26         0.237 0.0580 0.379 0.262 0.169 0.120 0.470
```

---

Data

```r
Ech_final_nom_SD <- read.table(header = T, text = "ID   Man Below_Master    Worker  Rural   Less_than_26    Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4  Q5  Q6
1   1   1   0   0   1   4   3   1   2   2   1
2   0   0   0   1   1   2   2   2   2   3   1
3   0   1   0   0   1   4   3   1   1   3   1
4   0   0   1   0   0   1   4   1   2   3   1
5   0   1   1   0   1   4   3   4   2   3   2
6   1   0   1   1   1   3   2   1   2   2   2
7   0   1   0   0   0   3   3   3   2   1   2
8   1   0   0   0   1   3   3   1   4   1   3
9   1   0   0   1   1   2   3   1   2   2   3
10  1   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   2   3")

independent_var <- c("Man", "Below_Master", "Worker", "Rural", "Less_than_26")
depending_var <- c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4", "Q5", "Q6")
```

Comment: Thanks, this is *almost* what I need but I would need to p-value instead of the intercept!

Comment: This *is* the p-value: the fourth column of the coefficients objects.

Comment: Take a look at `lapply(independant_var, function(x) summary(lm(reformulate(depending_var, x), data = Ech_final_nom_SD))$coefficients)` to make sure

Comment: My bad I hadnt seen the entire line, however I do get the following error message when using your solution : " 'termlabels' must be a character vector of length at least one"

Comment: This is only a formatting issue. You don't have to do `list(c(...))`, only `c` is needed (and should be used). This is why you get this error. I added the data I used to reproduce the results and you can see my `ind_var` and `depending_var` vector: they are not list. If you still this format, you can use `unlist`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you expect something like this?

```
Ech_final_nom_SD <- read.table(header = T, text = "
ID  Man     Below_Master    Worker  Rural   Less_than_26    Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4  Q5  Q6
1   1   1   0   0   1   4   3   1   2   2   1
2   0   0   0   1   1   2   2   2   2   3   1
3   0   1   0   0   1   4   3   1   1   3   1
4   0   0   1   0   0   1   4   1   2   3   1
5   0   1   1   0   1   4   3   4   2   3   2
6   1   0   1   1   1   3   2   1   2   2   2
7   0   1   0   0   0   3   3   3   2   1   2
8   1   0   0   0   1   3   3   1   4   1   3
9   1   0   0   1   1   2   3   1   2   2   3
10  1   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   2   3
                   ")
ind_var <- list(c("Man","Below_Master","Worker","Rural", "Less_than_26"))
dep_var <- list(c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4", "Q5", "Q6"))
pond <- rep(1, nrow(Ech_final_nom_SD))

x_list <- NULL
y_vec <- NULL

for (x in ind_var[[1]]) {
  for (y in dep_var[[1]]) {
    fit <- lm(paste(y, "~", x), data = Ech_final_nom_SD, weights = pond)
    p_value <- summary(fit)$coef[2,4]
    y_vec[y] <- p_value
  }
  x_list[[x]] <- y_vec
}
```

With output:

```
$Man
        Q1         Q2         Q3         Q4         Q5         Q6 
0.80277173 0.27313922 0.07359019 0.47136168 0.11143429 0.06558768 

$Below_Master
       Q1        Q2        Q3        Q4        Q5        Q6 
0.1869048 0.7244658 0.2622548 0.1264749 1.0000000 0.7404395 

$Worker
       Q1        Q2        Q3        Q4        Q5        Q6 
0.3455373 0.5621055 0.7410462 0.4619345 0.3558838 0.7870459 

$Rural
       Q1        Q2        Q3        Q4        Q5        Q6 
0.5447373 0.3876813 0.6363163 1.0000000 0.7482881 0.8286677 

$Less_than_26
        Q1         Q2         Q3         Q4         Q5         Q6 
0.05845715 0.93892908 0.90655491 0.43036607 0.62876991 0.82866767
```

I kept the *dep_var* and *ind_var* as lists as you intended. I renamed some of the variables though for clarity.

Comment: Hello Arifin, thank you for taking the time. Yes that is what I expected but someone managed to help me before you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tidyverse oriented variation :

```r
data <- read.table(header = T, text = "ID   Man Below_Master    Worker  Rural   Less_than_26    Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4  Q5  Q6
1   1   1   0   0   1   4   3   1   2   2   1
2   0   0   0   1   1   2   2   2   2   3   1
3   0   1   0   0   1   4   3   1   1   3   1
4   0   0   1   0   0   1   4   1   2   3   1
5   0   1   1   0   1   4   3   4   2   3   2
6   1   0   1   1   1   3   2   1   2   2   2
7   0   1   0   0   0   3   3   3   2   1   2
8   1   0   0   0   1   3   3   1   4   1   3
9   1   0   0   1   1   2   3   1   2   2   3
10  1   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   2   3")

ind_var <- c("Man","Below_Master","Worker","Rural", "Less_than_26")
depending_var <- c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4", "Q5", "Q6")

library(tidyverse)
pval_row <- function(data, depending_var, ind_var) {
  coefs <- summary(lm(reformulate(depending_var, ind_var), data))$coefficients
  set_names(tibble(!!!coefs[,"Pr(>|t|)"]), c("pval_intercept", "pval_indep"))
}

expand_grid(depending_var,ind_var) %>% 
  mutate(pmap_dfr(., pval_row, data = data))
#> # A tibble: 30 × 4
#>    depending_var ind_var      pval_intercept pval_indep
#>    <chr>         <chr>                 <dbl>      <dbl>
#>  1 Q1            Man                  0.226      0.803 
#>  2 Q1            Below_Master         0.893      0.187 
#>  3 Q1            Worker               0.101      0.346 
#>  4 Q1            Rural                0.229      0.545 
#>  5 Q1            Less_than_26         0.981      0.0585
#>  6 Q2            Man                  0.0828     0.273 
#>  7 Q2            Below_Master         0.286      0.724 
#>  8 Q2            Worker               0.251      0.562 
#>  9 Q2            Rural                0.194      0.388 
#> 10 Q2            Less_than_26         0.293      0.939 
#> # … with 20 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>